# Inconsistent sorting with sort()

Tags: python, sorting, counter

I have the following function to count words from a string and extract the top "n":

**Function**

```
def count_words(s, n):
"""Return the n most frequently occuring words in s."""

    #Split words into list
    wordlist = s.split()

    #Count words
    counts = Counter(wordlist)

    #Get top n words
    top_n = counts.most_common(n)

    #Sort by first element, if tie by second
    top_n.sort(key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))

    return top_n
```

So it sorts by occurance and if tied, alphabetically.
Following examples:

`print count_words("cat bat mat cat cat mat mat mat bat bat cat", 3)`

**works** (shows `[('cat', 4), ('mat', 4), ('bat', 3)]`)

`print count_words("betty bought a bit of butter but the butter was bitter", 3)`

**does not work** (shows `[('butter', 2), ('a', 1), ('bitter', 1)]` but should have `betty` instead of `bitter` as it they are tied and `be...` is before `bi...`)

`print count_words("betty bought a bit of butter but the butter was bitter", 6)`

**works** (shows `[('butter', 2), ('a', 1), ('betty', 1), ('bitter', 1), ('but', 1), ('of', 1)]` with `betty` before `bitter` as intended)

What could cause that (word-length maybe?) and how could I fix that?

Comment: You could fix it by doing `.most_common()`, then sorting and then slicing the result, instead of giving `n` to `most_common`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking for the top 3, and thus you cut of the data before you could have picked items in your specific sorting order.

Rather than have `most_common()` pre-sort then re-sort, use a `heapq` to sort by your custom criteria (provided `n` is smaller than the number of actual buckets):

```
import heapq

def count_words(s, n):
    """Return the n most frequently occuring words in s."""
    counts = Counter(s.split())
    key = lambda kv: (-kv[1], kv[0])
    if n >= len(counts):
        return sorted(counts.items(), key=key)
    return heapq.nsmallest(n, counts.items(), key=key)
```

On Python 2, you probably want to use `iteritems()` rather than `items()` for the above calls.

This re-creates the [`Counter.most_common()` method](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.5.2/Lib/collections/__init__.py#l537), but with the updated key. Like the original, using a `heapq` makes sure this is bound to O(NlogK) performance rather than O(NlogN) (with `N` the number of buckets, and K the top element count you want to see).

Demo:

```
>>> count_words("cat bat mat cat cat mat mat mat bat bat cat", 3)
[('cat', 4), ('mat', 4), ('bat', 3)]
>>> count_words("betty bought a bit of butter but the butter was bitter", 3)
[('butter', 2), ('a', 1), ('betty', 1)]
>>> count_words("betty bought a bit of butter but the butter was bitter", 6)
[('butter', 2), ('a', 1), ('betty', 1), ('bit', 1), ('bitter', 1), ('bought', 1)]
```

And a quick performance comparison (on Python 3.6.0b1):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> from heapq import nsmallest
>>> from random import choice, randrange
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> from string import ascii_letters
>>> sentence = ' '.join([''.join([choice(ascii_letters) for _ in range(randrange(3, 15))]) for _ in range(1000)])
>>> counts = Counter(sentence)  # count letters
>>> len(counts)
53
>>> key = lambda kv: (-kv[1], kv[0])
>>> timeit('sorted(counts.items(), key=key)[:3]', 'from __main__ import counts, key', number=100000)
2.119404911005404
>>> timeit('nsmallest(3, counts.items(), key=key)', 'from __main__ import counts, nsmallest, key', number=100000)
1.9657367869949667
>>> counts = Counter(sentence.split())  # count words
>>> len(counts)
1000
>>> timeit('sorted(counts.items(), key=key)[:3]', 'from __main__ import counts, key', number=10000)  # note, 10 times fewer
6.689963405995513
>>> timeit('nsmallest(3, counts.items(), key=key)', 'from __main__ import counts, nsmallest, key', number=10000)
2.902360848005628
```

Answer (score 10):

The problem is not the `sort` call but the `most_common`. The `Counter` is implemented as an hash table, as such the order it uses is *arbitrary*. When you ask for `most_common(n)` it will return the `n` most common words, and if there are ties it just decides arbitrarily which one to return!

The simplest way to solve this is to just avoid using `most_common` and directly use the list:

```
top_n = sorted(counts.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))[:n]
```

Comment: Please don't use `sorted()`, then cut. If the number of buckets is large this wastes a considerable amount of time. Use `heapq.nsmallest()` and only execute O(NlogK) steps rather than O(NlogN).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm well aware of that and of `heapq` too. But I don't think that it really matters, since it's a change in a logarithmic factor which thus requires exponentially big data to matter... and with exponentially big data you'll have a lot of issue anyway, especially using things like `Counter` that being a hashtable wastes quite some space...

Comment: You really don't need a huge hash to see the difference add up; see [this quick timing test](https://gist.github.com/mjpieters/3831d567f8ec4e0adc4c0fbc830f9326). That's picking the top 3 out of 53 for the letter count, and already the heapq wins. The heapq is  *not going to be slower*. When upped to 1000 unique words, the difference is striking.

Comment: Note that N is *multiplied* by the log of N or the log of K. log(1000) is still 9.97, while log(3) is only 1.58. Which translates more than double the speed for a heapq.nsmallest() approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could fix it by doing `.most_common()`, then sorting and then slicing the result, instead of giving `n` to `most_common`:

```
def count_words(s, n):
    """Return the n most frequently occuring words in s."""

    #Split words into list
    wordlist = s.split()

    #Count words
    counts = Counter(wordlist)

    #Sort by frequency
    top = counts.most_common()

    #Sort by first element, if tie by second
    top.sort(key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))

    return top[:n]
```

Comment: This does away entirely with the optimisations that `most_common()` includes; there is no point in having `most_common()` do the sorting and then discard most.

Comment: Good point, and a heapq is the better way, but I think this can help in understanding the issue.